# Get user events with Github API and Octokit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, github-api, octokit

I'm trying to make a simple call to retrieve user events on github through octokit.

According to the docs I create new client and visit the user events endpoint.

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: my_token)
user = client.user
```

Up to here it works fine, now I continue with

```
events = user.events
=> nil
```

Alternatively, when I do

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: my_token, api_endpoint: 'users/:user/events')
```

I get

```
#<Octokit::Client:0x007f9a78ac04f8...
```

but how to get list of events from there?
Here is the official doc https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-events-performed-by-a-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: my_token)
user = client.user
events = client.user_events user.login
```

It isn't exactly intuitive and I had to read the [source](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/lib/octokit/client/events.rb#L27). I haven't had a chance to test this yet but there doesn't appear to be a better way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you were close. Here is how to retrieve events `events = client.user_events(user.login)`

Comment: @olivier feel free to edit my answer then :D That aside, I feel like that might be a bug. I thought octokit accepted objects as well as strings but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @olivier sorry that they rejected your edit. Had I been online and seen it, I would havea ccepted it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
client = Octokit::Client::new(access_token: my_token)
                        ^^
```

Should be:

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: my_token)
                        ^
```

Comment: correct but it's a typo. I'm able to connect but not retrieve the data I'm looking for. any idea?